# what is the best way to split string in c#

Tags: c#, split

I have a string that look like that `"a,b,c,d,e,1,4,3,5,8,7,5,1,2,6....` and so on.
I am looking for the best way to split it and make it look like that:

```
a                     b              c              d              e

1                     4              3               5              8

7                      5              1              2               6
```

Comment: And how you describe `best way` ? `input.Split(',');`  will help you

Comment: `yourstring.Split(',');` or if you want to separate them by space then just replace `,` yourstring.Relace(","," ")`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, that you have a fix number of columns (5):

```
string Input = "a,b,c,d,e,11,45,34,33,79,65,75,12,2,6";
int i = 0;
string[][] Result = Input.Split(',').GroupBy(s => i++/5).Select(g => g.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

First I split the string by , character, then i group the result into chunks of 5 items and select those chunks into arrays.

Result:

```
a    b    c    d    e
11   45   34  33   79
65   75   12   2    6
```

to write that result into a file you have to

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer =new System.IO.StreamWriter(path,false))
{
    foreach (string[] line in Result)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(string.Join("\t", line)); 
    }
};
```

Comment: what is the s  (s => i++ / 5) and the g((g => g.ToArray());  stands for?

Comment: first i split the string by `,` character, then i group it into chunks of 5 items and select those chunks into arrays

Comment: sorry, i will explain my self better,  i have a string with values in the next form: a,b,c,d,e,1,2,3,4,5,8,9,4,5,6.... and so on,  i want to split it to the form you show before (result) and the save the result string  in to a file

Comment: thanks, its working , but i have a problem, the original string have a char that was probly insert there to make space or somthing else but there is no "," between the letter e and the first number so the new string is ont correct.  it looks like that  a,b,c,d,d,e***11,45,34,33,79,65,75   many thanks for all the help